# How to specialize a template for 2 different values?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Given the code below, I was wondering if it is possible to have a specialization for a set of values. In my example, I want to create an specialization for `N=3` or `N=4` to use an array of known size. Is it possible to avoid code duplication in this case?

```
template <typename T, unsigned int N>
class A
{
public:
    T* data;
};

template <typename T>
class A<T, 3>
{
public:
    T data[3];
};

template <typename T>
class A<T, 4>
{
public:
    T data[4];
};

int main()
{
    A<int, 1> u;
    std::cout << sizeof(u.data) << std::endl; // Size of pointer

    A<int, 3> v;
    std::cout << sizeof(v.data) << std::endl; // Size of data

    A<int, 4> w;
    std::cout << sizeof(w.data) << std::endl; // Size of data

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) by introducing a *default `void` template parameter* in the general case.

```
template <typename T, unsigned int N, typename = void>
class A
{
public:
    T* data;
};

template <typename T, unsigned int N>
class A<T, N, typename std::enable_if<N == 3 || N == 4>::type>
{
public:
    T data[N];
};
```

[**live wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gmkM7exAhbTK6QOE)

---

If `N == 3 || N == 4` is `true`, then `typename std::enable_if<N == 3 || N == 4>::type` is **well-formed** and evaluates to `void`. The specialization is then chosen.

If `N == 3 || N == 4` is `false`, then `typename std::enable_if<N == 3 || N == 4>::type` is **ill-formed** and the specialization is *"SFINAEd away"*. The general case is then chosen.

Comment: Awesome it works. I guess this is some kind of metaprogramming in C++? I'm not used to it and want to know so that I can grab a book and start learning it because that "SFINAEd" I do not understand.

Comment: @BRabbit27: yes, this is a form of metaprogramming. I don't really have a book to recommend (sorry), but if you Google for "sfinae" and "template metaprogramming c++11" then you'll probably find useful resources.