# What is the full type qualification of a class template?

Tags: c++, templates

Following the answer in this post [How to specialize a template for 2 different values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786250/how-to-specialize-a-template-for-2-different-values/43786319?noredirect=1#comment74613780_43786319) I wanted to implement the functions outside the class definition but I cannot seem to find what is the full type qualification for this class template

```
template <typename T, unsigned int N, typename = void>
class A
{
    A();
public:
    T* data;
};

template <typename T, unsigned int N>
class A<T, N, typename std::enable_if<N == 3 || N == 4>::type>
{
    A();
public:
    T data[N];
};
```

So far I've tried

```
template <typename T, unsigned int N, typename>
A<T,N>::A(){}  //expected a ';' + expected a type specifier + expected an identifier

template <typename T, unsigned int N, typename>
A<T,N,typename>::A(){}  //same errors but I believe this doesnt make sense at all
```

Moreover, how to differentiate between the general template and the specialization when writing the actual code for the member functions?

Comment: Please post all the relevant information in the question - don't rely on the fact that others will follow a link. Remember that a good [MCVE] is the key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way of implementing the function outside of the `class` definition is as follows:

```
template <typename T, unsigned int N, typename U>
A<T, N, U>::A() { }

template <typename T, unsigned int N>
A<T, N, typename std::enable_if<N == 3 || N == 4>::type>::A() { }
```

In the first case, even if `void` is provided as a *default template argument*, you still need to "match" it. Think about of the case where some user provides a type that's different from `void`.

In the second case, you unfortunately need to repeat the `enable_if` logic - this is a good use case for a *type alias*, and a good example of why implementing *member functions* inside a *class template* definition is preferable to outside definitions.

Comment: Ok I see, the template parameter's name was just avoided since it was not used inside the template. I thin `template <typename T, unsigned int N, typename = void>` is the same as `template <typename T, unsigned int N, typename U = void>` which now makes more sense.